# Detecting Enter key press on a button c#

Tags: c#, winforms

This piece of code detect most keys and puts it in a messageBox, but one of the keys it doesn't is the enter key.  *Note it is a ***key_down*** method

```
MessageBox.Show(e.KeyData.ToString());
```

so far I have tried so many methods to fix and searched a lot for an answer 
I have tried this

```
private void button1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {


        MessageBox.Show("this is it");
        e.IsInputKey = true;
    }

}
```

it **says 0 references** which I know I'm not calling the method but where do I call it? 
where ever I do call it, it gives an error.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Keyboard` static class? I think it might help you

Comment: Put this line soon after: `InitializeComponents();` --> `button1.PreviewKeyDown +=new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(button1_PreviewKeyDown);`

Comment: No, but I will check it out for certain. @Alex

Comment: The event you're trying to use will only fire when you focus on that button. The focus is passed in 2 different ways ( via user interaction ) one of which is an actual mouse click on that element and another is "tabbing" on to the control.

Comment: What Sunil said and read about "Events" and "EventHandlers".

Comment: Now it does work properly, thank you @Sunil

Comment: You say your code works for all key presses but the enter key, yet you haven’t even registered your handler? Sorry, but I don’t believe you.

Comment: Your button1_PreviewKeyDown method is an event handler: it handles the event PreviewKeyDown of button1. If you have 0 references to it then you have to "connect" the event PreviewKeyDown of button1 with this event handler. To do so you can go to the design of your form, click on the button and on Properties search for the Event and select this event handler.

Comment: for most keys! @poke

Comment: ah I get it now! thank you all 
@Fleve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Form1 Design Properties:

`AcceptButton` Property set dropdown to `button1` or the name of your `Button`

KeyUp Event of your Button

```
private void button1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Enter key has been pressed");
      }
}
```

or

```
 private void button1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            button1_KeyDown(sender, e);
        }

        private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter key has been pressed");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

you delete this line

```
 e.IsInputKey = true;
```

```
 private void button1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("this is it");
            //e.IsInputKey = true;
        }
    }
```

or

```
    private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("this is it");
            //e.IsInputKey = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this line soon after: `InitializeComponents();` --> 
`button1.PreviewKeyDown +=new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(button1_PreviewKeyDown);`
.

The event you're trying to use will only fire when you focus on that button. The focus is passed in 2 different ways ( via user interaction ) one of which is an actual mouse click on that element and another is "tabbing" on to the control, and make sure you read about "Events" and "EventsHandlers"